# Link padre en menú desplegable

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

tengo la siguiente estructura para un menú desplegable:

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <ul class="submenu text-center">
    <li>... </li>
    <li> ...</li>
    <li>... </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

El problema me surge cuando quiero enlazar el padre con un link, no sé como hacerlo. Gracias

```html
<li class="dropdown"> Enlace_hacia_otra_pagina
  <ul class="submenu text-center">
    <li>... </li>
    <li> ...</li>
    <li>... </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: ¿Exactamente qué no te funciona? A mí me funciona perfectamente tu código, "Padre" es un enlace que va a una página llamada "...".

Comment: @miaweb, ¿podrías explicar con palabras qué es lo que esperas que haga tu HTML? Es decir, ¿qué quieres decir con que quieres enlazar el padre a una página? ¿Que haya un texto en el punto padre que al pulsarlo vaya a un enlace y que los hijos no? ¿Es un menú desplegable en el que quieres que al pulsar al nodo padre se vaya a un enlace? (¡¡ojo!!, ¡eso impediría que los usuarios desplegaran el menú en móviles y dispositivos táctiles!).

Comment: Quiero decir que haya un texto en el punto padre que al pulsarlo vaya a un enlace y que los hijos no. Los hijos solo aparecen si se pasa el ratón encima del punto padre. En cuanto a moviles y resto de dispositivos si no funciona no pasa nada, tengo otro código para ese caso.  No sé si me he explicado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` son cada uno de los elementos de la lista.

Prueba a cambiar la etiqueta a `<ul>`.

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
  <a href="https://google.es"> Padre </a>
  <ul class="submenu text-center">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li> ...</li>
  </ul>  
</ul>
```

Comment: No deberías responder sin tener claro lo que pregunta ni cuál es su problema y si tu respuesta realmente soluciona su problema. Por cierto, las etiquetas `<ul>` deberían tener en su interior etiquetas `<li>` y tú has introducido un `<a>` [violando la especificación del formato HTML](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-ul-element).

Comment: @miaweb para hacerlo debes [**editar tu pregunta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/98173/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás buscando es utilizar un [elemento HTML anchor`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a) dentro de tu lista. 
Como referencia, cualquier elemento HTML que sea válido dentro de un `<div>` también lo es en `<li>`.

```html
<ul> <!-- Menú -->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Enlace_hacia_otra_pagina</a>
    <ul class="submenu text-center">
      <li>... </li>
      <li> ...</li>
      <li>... </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```